# C++ pimpl idiom and static method and fields

Tags: c++, static, static-methods, pimpl-idiom

I would like to better understand how to use static field an method in the presence of PIMPL idiom.
Consider the following code.

MyClass.h file:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS
#define MYCLASS

class MyClass{
     public:
     void method();
     static void static_method();

     private:
     Type field;
     static Type *static_field;
}

#endif
```

MyClass.cpp file:

```
#include MyClass.h

void MyClass::method(){
     /*OK method definition*/
     field = new Type();   /*OK field construction*/
}

void MyClass::static_method(){
     /*NOT WORKING method declaraion */
     static_field = new Type();   /*not working */
}
```

I have these 2 errors:

1. cannot declare member function static_method to have a static linkage
2. static_field was not declared in this scope

I'm not very familiar with pimpl idiom.

So my question is how I achieve static methods and fields declarations to respect the PIMPL idiom and compile it successfully?

What am I doing wrong in this code?

How have I to change my code?

Comment: `field` and `static_field` must be pointers to `Type` instead of type `Type`.

Comment: @Dialecticus: was an other error. It's a pointer in my actual implementaion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Show us actual code that you've verified produces the same error
- Don't put static in front of the function definition in the .cpp file
- You don't have a `static_field` - you have two `field`

Comment: sorry but I come from java language where a static variable exist. How i declare a static variable in c++?

Comment: What Erik is saying is that you have `static Type field` in your code, where you obviously meant `static Type static_field`.

Comment: @0verbose, Erik gave you correct answer. Check out this link (courtesy of Google): http://cplusplus.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Cannot_declare_member_function_%E2%80%98static_int_Foo::bar%28%29%E2%80%99_to_have_static_linkage

Answer (score 2):

The purpose if pimpl is to eliminate compilation dependencies. The fact that a pimpl class has a private static member is an implementation detail and thus should not be in the header file or in the pimpl class definition.

Put you private statics into the .cc/.cpp file in an unnamed namespace along with the definitions of the member functions of the pimpl class.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, u need to have the definiton

```
Type* MyClass::static_field = new Type();
```

at u'r cpp file. this is because this way u tell the compiler at what object file the field should be instantiated, otherwise the compiler has no way to know.